# How many stable equilibrium points are there for a generic floating body?

Tags: fluid-statics

Given a convex solid with uniform density and no symmetry (not a ball, not a cube, not a cylinder, not a rugby ball...), which is less than the density of water, if it's thrown into water, it will float.

How many stable equilibrium points can it settle into?

Since it has to balance somehow, there must be at least one stable equilibrium. Of course, if the solid has a symmetry group G, then the solid has at least |G| many stable equilibria. So if the solid is a ball, it would have infinitely many stable (neutral) equilibria. So we require the solid to have no symmetries.